# Mimetype-fu isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I feel like this should be an easy answer but I'm totally stumped.

I've added mimetype_fu to my gemfile and it installed it when I ran bundle install. When I try to use File.mime_type? in my application I get an error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `mime_type?' for File:Class
```

In the rails console when I run

```
gem 'mimetype-fu'
```

it returns true

I'm on windows, if that matters

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to manually `require` it inside your rails app.  You can do this by adding an file to `config/initializers/` if you want it to be available globally.

EDIT | Also, you did restart the rails server, right? ;)

Comment: Awesome, that's what I needed.

For anyone else that has this problem it's require 'mimetype_fu' not require 'mimetype-fu'

Comment: that sucks! it took me 30 mins to see this comment

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Bundler, you can also just add require to the gem line like this.

```
gem 'mimetype-fu', :require => 'mimetype_fu'
```

Comment: A better solution then adding an initializer!